# Equivalent to minus in netezza

Tags: sql, syntax, netezza

I want to compare data between two different db tables in netezza. In oracle we can do that by minus operator. How can the same operation be done in netezza.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID,CUSTOMER_SRC_DESC FROM  CIDB_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC 
MINUS 
SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID,CUSTOMER_SRC_DESC FROM EDW_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC
```

Seems like it doesn't work in netezza. Can any one help me find the equivalent query in netezza?

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI-SQL standard calls this operators `except`. Netezza [implements it](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_combine_tbls_union_intersect_except.html), as do PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID,CUSTOMER_SRC_DESC FROM CIDB_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC 
EXCEPT -- Here
SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID,CUSTOMER_SRC_DESC FROM EDW_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EXCEPT

or

--if customer_src_id is unique--

SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID,CUSTOMER_SRC_DESC 
FROM CIDB_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC
WHERE CUSTOMER_SRC_ID NOT IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_SRC_ID FROM EDW_SIT..CUSTOMER_SRC);